# ContentBox giving error on installation

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

I am currently trying to install ContentBox 2 on my machine. 
I am using ColdFusion 9.0.2, MySQL 5.6 and IIS 7 on Windows 7 Professional.
I have created database named “contentbox” and created a datasource named “contentbox” for it
as mentioned  by the ContentBox documentation.

When I try to setup ContentBox, I’m presented with a datasource wizard page.
The wizard successfully verifies the datasource and gives me option to continue the setup.
On clicking the “continue installation” button  I get the following error message:
`Table cb_entry defined for cfc contentbox.model.content.Entry does not exist`.
I’ve already given read/write permission to all the mentioned files and folders.
Can you help me sort out this issue.

Comment: The error seems to be referencing a database table, not files or folders. It says the table `cb_entry` does not exist. Did you create that table and does your datasource user have rights to it?

Comment: @Miguel-F The ContentBox documentation says that the required tables will be automatically created by the framework, during installation. The datasource has the rights to create tables (root user). I contacted Ortus Solutions support. They advised to use ContentBox version 2.1 (Bleeding edge release). Version 2.0 has some issues with CF9. This seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Please post that as an answer to your question. It may help someone else later that is having the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got the problem solved.
I contacted Ortus Solutions support. They advised to use ContentBox version 2.1 (Bleeding edge release) as Version 2.0 has some issues with CF9.
I have downloaded and installed the new version.
And it seems to be working fine.